# Virtual Earth Shape Rendering Performance

Tags: bing-maps, virtual-earth

I am overlaying a transparent image on my VEMap control by rendering it as a single VEShape. The shape changes sizes dynamically depeding on the zoom level of my map and can be as large as 4000*4000px.  In older browsers such as IE6 and early versions of Firefox 2.x, map control performance degrades rapidly when my shape gets larger than 1500*1500px. The mouse pointer moves slowly and the map responds very slowly to events. I don't see this issue at all in newer browsers (IE7+).

Are there any workarounds to boost performance of rendering a large shape for IE6 users?

Answer (score 0):

The solution you're probably looking for is to actually use "Map Cruncher" to create map tile images from your image. Then these map tile images can be overlaid on the VEMap using a Custom Tile Layer, and will be rendered exactly the same way as the Map Images themselves.

http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/mapcruncher.aspx